# Trying to identify unkown code we have to work on?

Tags: .net, xml, system.net

This question may seem a bit dumb, but I am learning new code everyday like most of us.  I have a brief pseudo code a company provided with little to no support we are working on a citation program.  what language utilizes     "xmlResult"  and

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback 
    = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(RemoteCertificateValidationCallback);
```

Thank You

Comment: The particular syntax looks like C#, however potentially any .NET CLR language could be used in its place.

Comment: If it's "psuedo code" then it could be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of languages support those calls.  They are both supported in .net, which means the implementations could be in a few different languages.  Complete and total guess, but likely C#.  Pseudocode is just that, code that isn't written in a particular language yet, but gets the idea across of what is being done.

Here is the MSDN article on [ServicePointManager.Server.CertificateValidationCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144153.aspx)

Comment: This looks like it might be ASP and C#, but again, just a guess based on the look.  Rather than try and deconstruct the pseudocode they have given you, you might be better off just trying to figure out what they want you to do, and then write it for the Android.